# How to remove columns from an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

This is the (3x9) array:

```
    [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
     [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
     [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]]
```

I want to have it like this (3x3):

```
    [[ 2  7  8]
     [11 16 17]
     [20 25 26]]
```

I wrote some code.
Is there a better way to do it?

```
    AB = x[:,2:] #Removes the first 2 columns
    print(AB)
    C = np.delete(AB, 1, 1)
    print(C)
    D = np.delete(C, 1, 1)
    print(D)
    E = np.delete(D, 1, 1)
    print(E)
    F = np.delete(E, 1, 1)
    print(F)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    index = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]     #Set the index of columns I want to remove
    new_a = np.delete(x, index, 1) #x=name of array
                                   #index=calls the index array
                                   #1=is the axis. So the columns
    print(new_a)                   #Print desired array
```

Comment: Yep, looks cleaner (+1). Fix your indentation

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `bulk` delete in plain python, using `zip` and `enumerate`:

```
cols_to_del = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
AB_trans = [v for i, v in enumerate(zip(*AB)) if i not in cols_to_del]
AB = np.array(list(zip(*AB_trans)))
print(AB)
# array([[ 2,  7,  8],
#        [11, 16, 17],
#        [20, 25, 26]])
```

The idea is to transpose the array, and delete the columns (which are now presented as rows).

Comment: Thank you. I did it with 2 lines of code. Although yours is "brainy"